# Как заполнить список точек

Tags: c#, list

Хочу создать несколько прямых с определенным шагом. Как правильно занести эти данные в список точек? То есть, `begin` и `end` это точки начала и конца прямой с тремя координатами в каждой.

```
List<XYZ> begin = new List<XYZ>();
List<XYZ> end = new List<XYZ>();
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    begin.Add({ (0), (step * i), (0)});
    end.Add({ (10), (step * i), (0)});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

так попробуйте

```
List<Point3D> begin = new List<Point3D>();
List<Point3D> end = new List<Point3D>();
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    begin.Add(new Point3D(0, step * i, 0));
    end.Add(new Point3D(10 , (step * i), 0));
}
```

если так не хотите то так

```
List<Object> begin = new List<Object>();
List<Object> end = new List<Object>();
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    begin.Add(new { x = 0, y = step * i, z = 0));
    end.Add(new { x = 10 , y = step * i, z = 0));
}
```

только в этом случае будите сами выковыривать значения из списков, но значения будут там.

Answer (score 1):

Правильней будет создать список примитивов и определить класс примитив

```
class Primitiv{
Point3D begin;
Point3D end;

Primitiv(Point3D begin,Point3D end){this.begin = begin;this.end = end;}
}

List<Primitiv> lines = new List<Primitiv>();
```